# .htacces set 410 gone to com_k2 links

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to make a 410 (gone) to all com_k2 links that for some reason are pointing towards my site, but the WordPress part of `htaccess` (I mean # BEGIN WordPress - # END WordPress) overrides it and I can't make it work.

This is what I have at the top of site:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mypage.com
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} com_k2 [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [G,L]
```

then at the bottom WP makes this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

The pattern is this:

```
https://www.mypage.com/?option=com_k2&view=itemlist&task=user&id=5640
```

I'm no htaccess expert so... help!

This is the full htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WpFastestCache
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mitza\.es
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} com_k2 [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [G]
# Start WPFC Exclude
# End WPFC Exclude
# Start_WPFC_Exclude_Admin_Cookie
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !wordpress_logged_in_[^\=]+\=mitza@mitza.es
# End_WPFC_Exclude_Admin_Cookie
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mitza.es
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(facebookexternalhit|WhatsApp|Mediatoolkitbot)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\/){2}$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !.+
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !comment_author_
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !wp_woocommerce_session
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !safirmobilswitcher=mobil
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Profile} !^[a-z0-9\"]+ [NC]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/cache/all/$1/index.html -f [or]
RewriteCond /home/mitzaes/public_html/wp-content/cache/all/$1/index.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*) "/wp-content/cache/all/$1/index.html" [L]
</IfModule>
<FilesMatch "index\.(html|htm)$">
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
FileETag None
Header unset ETag
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
Header set Pragma "no-cache"
Header set Expires "Mon, 29 Oct 1923 20:30:00 GMT"
</ifModule>
</FilesMatch>
# END WpFastestCache
# BEGIN GzipWpFastestCache
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
AddType x-font/woff .woff
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype font/ttf font/eot font/otf
</IfModule>
# END GzipWpFastestCache
# BEGIN LBCWpFastestCache
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|webp|js|css|swf|x-html|css|xml|js|woff|woff2|ttf|svg|eot)(\.gz)?$">
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
AddType application/font-woff2 .woff2
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault A0
ExpiresByType image/webp A2592000
ExpiresByType image/gif A2592000
ExpiresByType image/png A2592000
ExpiresByType image/jpg A2592000
ExpiresByType image/jpeg A2592000
ExpiresByType image/ico A2592000
ExpiresByType image/svg+xml A2592000
ExpiresByType text/css A2592000
ExpiresByType text/javascript A2592000
ExpiresByType application/javascript A2592000
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript A2592000
ExpiresByType application/font-woff2 A2592000
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Expires "max-age=2592000, public"
Header unset ETag
Header set Connection keep-alive
FileETag None
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
# END LBCWpFastestCache


# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress
# BEGIN Brute Force Login Protection
<FilesMatch ".*\.(php|html?|css|js|jpe?g|png|gif)$">
order deny,allow
deny from 91.200.12.22
deny from 91.200.12.91
deny from 2607:f298:5:101b::61e:49ae
</FilesMatch>
# END Brute Force Login Protection
RewriteEngine on
Redirect 301 /nuevo-nicehash-miner-legacy https://www.mitza.es/noticias/nuevo-nicehash-miner-legacy
Redirect 301 /secciones/bitcoin/ https://www.mitza.es/zonas/paginas-web-valdemoro
Redirect 301 /secciones/litecoin/ https://www.mitza.es/zonas/paginas-web-valdemoro
Redirect 301 /portfolio/gibson-guitars/ https://www.mitza.es/zonas/paginas-web-valdemoro
Redirect 301 /portfolio/nex7-workspace/ https://www.mitza.es/zonas/paginas-web-valdemoro
Redirect 301 /how-videos-can-help-promote-your-business/ https://www.mitza.es/zonas/paginas-web-valdemoro
Redirect 301 /working-like-a-workaholic/ https://www.mitza.es/zonas/paginas-web-valdemoro
Redirect 301 /portfolio/focus-lab/ https://www.mitza.es/zonas/paginas-web-valdemoro
Redirect 301 /portfolio/outdoor-photoshoot/ https://www.mitza.es/zonas/paginas-web-valdemoro
Redirect 301 /portfolio/l-a-p-d-1947/ https://www.mitza.es/zonas/paginas-web-valdemoro
Redirect 301 /audio-post/ https://www.mitza.es/zonas/paginas-web-valdemoro
Redirect 301 /perfect-sunday-morning-ride/ https://www.mitza.es/zonas/paginas-web-valdemoro
Redirect 301 /secciones/noticias/ https://www.mitza.es/noticias
#2
Redirect 301 /logic-will-get-you-from-a-to-b/ https://www.mitza.es/
Redirect 301 /component/content/article/2-uncategorised/80-para-costi https://www.mitza.es
Redirect 301 /role-of-size-in-logo-design/ https://www.mitza.es/
Redirect 301 /portfolio/its-summer-time/ https://www.mitza.es/
Redirect 301 /portfolio/maybe-one-day-fashion/ https://www.mitza.es/
Redirect 301 /hello-world-2/ https://www.mitza.es/
Redirect 301 /hola-mundo/ https://www.mitza.es/
Redirect 301 /try-me https://www.mitza.es/
Redirect 301 /poze-cu-elsa https://www.mitza.es/
Redirect 301 /portfolio/sea-side-store/ https://www.mitza.es/
Redirect 301 /portfolio/time-is-nothing/ https://www.mitza.es/
Redirect 301 /category/noticias https://www.mitza.es/
# BEGIN WP Performance Score Booster Settings
# END WP Performance Score Booster Settings
Redirect 301 /case-study-envato-website-redesign/ https://www.mitza.es/
```

Answer (score 0):

@ This line :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mypage.com
```

You should escape spacial character like this :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mypage\.com
```

If you want to match both `www` or `non-www`  replace with this :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mypage\.com
```

Comment: @Mitzayapa no need to [G,L] only [G]

Comment: redirect path plugin shows a 301 then a 410 but the page still loads , how's that possible ?

Comment: changed to G only , but why is the page still loading ?

Comment: @Mitzayapa When using [G], an [L] is implied - that is, the response is returned immediately, and no further rules are evaluated.

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html

Comment: @Mitzayapa get this line out RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on and test it

Comment: Yep , does it load to you ?

Comment: @Mitzayapa it works fine for me , paste what in you htaccess exactly

Comment: You mean , it loads ? if its an 410 it souldn't load right ?

Comment: @Mitzayapa it gives Gone
The requested resource
/
is no longer available on this server and there is no forwarding address. Please remove all references to this resource. as expected

Comment: @Mitzayapa save your code then test the first rule alone just this                RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mitza\.es
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} com_k2 [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [G]

Comment: Leaving only the first part, the 410 works as should but every one of my inner pages/posts gives me an 404.

Comment: @Mitzayapa so the code is running but there are rules that prevent it from being done , try to put other rules one by one and overriding happen , but make sure you save the first file copy away

Comment: the ·#wordpress code is overriding the first part.But my wp wont work without it.